# Sorting program gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm currently stuck on that little programm in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int a[], int n) {

   
    int index =0;
    while (index <= n-1){
        while (index != a[index]){
            int temp;
            temp = a[index];
            a[index] = a[temp];
            a[temp] = temp;
            printf("%d\n", temp);

        }
      
        index = index+1;
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);

    }

}

int main() {
  int A[] = {0,6,5,1,3,20};
  int n=6;

  print(A,n);

return 0;

}
```

I have no idea why its not sorting and giving me that error...

Kind regard and thanks in advance

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Tip: `int x = 0; while (x < n) { ...; ++x; }` is better written as `for (int x = 0; x < n; ++x) { ... }`. You even use a `for` later on.

Comment: What is `while (index != a[index]){` doing? In that block you're doing some seriously strange things, including `a[temp] =` where `temp` could be *way* past the end of that array. For this to not crash all values in `A` must be at or below `n-1`.

Comment: well, its a complicated way to sort an array.... and no, I don't have a debugger...

Comment: **Get a debugger**. You need one. This is not optional. C effectively requires one in order to deal with problems like this without guessing and wasting time. Secondly, that isn't a "complicated way", it's not a sort algorithm at all.

Comment: There are many [well known sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) you can implement (if you need to, otherwise use `qsort()`) but whatever you're doing here doesn't seem to be the right idea. I'd test this on paper first because I think you'll quickly find it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: oh yeahh you right... we got the pseudocode for that and had to solve it by hand. just wanted to recreate it in c but doesnt make sense at all

Comment: @safetimenow you don't have a debugger!? What kind of strange platform are you using? What is your OS, IDE, compiler, environment etc.?

Comment: @safetimenow showing us that pseudo code might help

Comment: could you recommend me a debugger? compiler is gcc

Comment: @safetimenow are you programming in php or in C?

Comment: C, but phpstorm is nice iDE... are the better ones? haha

Comment: GCC has GDB. Others, like VCC ([Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com)) are much more integrated and easier to use. Don't use tools like phpstorm that are suited for PHP far better than for C.

Comment: Which sorting algorithm are you attempting to implement? Also, I would recommend keeping the sorting function separate from the printing function.